# Changing text in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function, settimeout

This works but only half way. It'll change the element I want changed but it changes immediately instead of after 9 seconds. Sorry if this is a dumb question I'm new and not sure if this is even how to change text the correct way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    setTimeout(changeText,9000);

    function changeText(){
         var textChange = document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = 'IS LIfe'; 
    }

    changeText();
</script>
```

Comment: remove this line changeText();
This line will call the function on page load.

Comment: Wow that was it i feel dumb. Thank you so much though!

Answer (score 1):

The setTimeout is not the only place that you are calling the function, you're also calling it at the end. Remove the last call and it will work.

```
setTimeout(changeText,9000); 
function changeText(){ 
  var textChange = document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = 'IS LIfe'; 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the text only after 9 seconds, please remove the last line of function calling. That is triggering when page loads.

```
setTimeout(changeText,9000); 

function changeText(){ 
var textChange = document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = 'IS LIfe'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `changeText();` at the bottom. It is an extra call and not-needed since `setTimeout` will invoke your callback